# Can I define a type of non-arrow function in ts?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I can define a function type like this:

```
type MyCallback = (para: number|string)=> string
```

These functions will be used as event callbacks, so I want a normal function rather than arrow functions to avoid `this` issues occurring in arrow functions.

Is there a way to define a type that only allows normal functions?

Comment: `type MyCallback = (number|string)=> string` is not valid TypeScript. Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WzAj2m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Also, when you say you want to use the functions as "event callbacks", can you provide a [mre] of a usage you want to support and one you want to prohibit?  Possibly a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) will let you distinguish "normal" functions from arrow functions in the way you care about, but without a functioning example it's hard to be sure.

Comment: @jcalz, I revised it.

Comment: Great, but I'm still wondering about usages.  If you use a `this` parameter you get some of the benefits you're looking for... see [this code example here](https://tsplay.dev/wR5r7W).  You've already accepted the other answer so this might just be academic at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript actually doesn't distinguish between arrow functions and regular functions when it comes to the type of a function. So the you are fine using the arrow function type to represent any callback:

```
type MyCallback = (param: number|string)=> string

function onValue(fn: MyCallback) {
  return fn(0)
}

onValue(o => o.toString())
onValue(function (o) { return o.toString() })
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDCBDANsgRogxgaygXigAoxEAnRAWwC4oA7AVwrQlIB8BnYUgS1oHMAlHgB8UTj34BYAFAyAZvVqZg3APa0o6gGop6EQnNo04SVBhwCoAbxlQopCMHqkNhwgAYBMgL4yZ23X1VfFFVADpgVQBlLl4+QgEvaQDkPQNFZTUNQlVLK3tHZw1wyJiJeMtvASA)

There is a non arrow syntax for function signatures, but it's usually used when you have to define overloads:

```
type MyCallback = {
  (param: string): string
  (param: number): string
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDCBDANsgRogxgaygXigG8BYAKCigAoxEAnRAWwC4oBnYWgSwDsBzAShbsufMhWp1GLbgFcGaCLUFsOPXmQC+ZMgDMZ3TME4B7blFMA1FDIiUd3FnCSoMOfkTFRaEYDNpn7SgAGfk1tUktrW2N8AD5zADpgYwBlVT5KflCI7itkGzt9QxMzSmN3Qi8fPzNjJNT03kyoDX4gA)